# PHP - Empty value that converts to false

Tags: php

At a logical level I think about empty as a construct that checks if a variable is empty.

This means that imo (again, at a logical level), this makes sense:

```
if (!empty($a) && $a) {/* do something */}
```

Still... I can't find any case where the second check ($a is true) makes sense in the "real world".

So... is there any case where the following is true (personally I couldn't find any)?

```
(!empty($a) && $a) != (empty($a))
```

Comment: can you share value of `$a`.

Comment: `empty()` checks for an empty value, zero value, undefined or null value, etc

Comment: http://3960.org/sandbox/empty.php

Comment: may be string count function help you

Comment: apriede understood the question :). It was hypothetical, I'm not looking for something specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is a purely hypothetical, if not please provide some context.

To answer what you asked $a will simply be parsed to a boolean value if put in a conditional. And empty() will check if a value can be considered empty. So essentially you are asking if it is possible for a value to be parsed as FALSE and not be empty() or a value to be parsed TRUE and be considered empty() ?

If you compare the man pages for [boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) and for [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) you can see pretty much an identical overlap.

The answer: no your condition will never be true as !empty($a) && $a is redundant to simply !empty($a)

Comment: Purely hypothetical, yes.

Answer (score 1):

[*"Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty **if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE**. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist."*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

> Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE.
>
> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> "" (an empty string)
>
> 0 (0 as an integer)
>
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
>
> "0" (0 as a string)
>
> NULL
>
> FALSE
>
> array() (an empty array)
>
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

Answer (score -1):

You can try these :-

```
if (!empty($a) && ($a != "")) 
{
   /* do something */
}
```

Second option :-

```
if (!empty($a) && (count($a) > 0)) 
{
   /* do something */
}
```

It may help you.

Comment: why not check for `null`?

Comment: `empty($a)` checks `$a == ""` so it's unnecesary